# Show message when start typing inside textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NETand I want to show message behind a textbox when I start to write in it, I want to do that on the client side so I think javascript is the key.

Edit :

My code:

```
<tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Alternate Email :"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="_txtAlternateEmail" runat="server" onkeyup="typetext(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Security Question :"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="_txtSecurityQuestion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function typetext(tb) {
        var mySpanElement = document.getElementById("_txtSecurityQuestion");
        mySpanElement.innerText = tb.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the text next to the textbox, as the user's typing it?

Comment: exactly and this text disappear if textbox is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `onkeyup` event in the textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtAlternateEmail" runat="server" onkeyup="typetext(this);">
</asp:TextBox>
```

which calls the `typetext` method. In your `typetext` method, you can set the `span` (or whatever HTML element) to the text of the textbox.

```
function typetext(tb)
{
     var mytextbox = document.getElementById('<%=_txtSecurityQuestion.ClientID %>');
     mytextbox.value = tb.value;
}
```

Comment: I tried but nothing changed, meanwhile I'm using the asp.net textbox not the normal html input text type

Comment: Please post your code. The above works with asp.net textboxes as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it writes to a textbox instead of a `span`. To get asp.net controls in Javascript, you need to use `<%= %>`. The above should now work.